# C# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm trying to make URLReader public string, to not dublicate it in every function. So i have something like this:

```
public static string URLReader(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Stream fileStream = webClient.OpenRead(url);
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("URL Not exists or you are not connected to internet!", "Problems!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return "";
        }
    }
```

I don't know why, but catch not working.. For example, if I write incorrect url, or disconnect from internet it must print for me that "URL Not exists or you are not connected to interned!" But I've give error in this line:

**Stream fileStream = webClient.OpenRead(url);**

Error:

> The first stage of processing exceptions of type
>       "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException" in System.dll
>       For more information: The requested name is correct, but the data requested type was found
>       If this exception handler is available, the program can be continued safely.

*P.S Error mesage translated by google translate, because I'm not english*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As it says in the error message, "If this exception handler is available, the program can be continued safely.". So the chances are you've just hit this in the debugger, and you wouldn't see it normally. You could change the debugger settings to indicate this, but whatever happens you need to give *detailed* descriptions of what's happening, rather than just "I've give error"...

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thanks, in release mode its work!